# Validate Certain PHP Class Methods are Called

Tags: php, class, methods

I have a Class where most of the Methods are required to run.
I normally call these methods after I've instantiated the Object.

```
<?php

try { 
   $obj = new MyClassName();
   $obj->Method1($var);
   $obj->Method2($var);
   $obj->Method3($var);
   $obj->Method4($var);

} catch(Exception $e) { 

}
?>
```

As my Class grows, and more Methods get introduced, I find that I need to ensure that certain Methods get called.

At first, I was calling all my required Methods within the `__construct()`, then calling those same Methods again, in case I need to alter things.

My other validation technique is to run `get_object_vars()` and check for the existence of specific properties.

I don't mind my current way to validate, but I have to inquire if there's an easier/better way.

Comment: I would in generally say the constructor is the place for them

Comment: do you have to validate only certain methods or all ?

Comment: This seems like a broken design to me, though it's so abstract it's hard to say.

Comment: Not really knowing the code sounds kinda like you might benefit from some sort of [Dependency Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection).  Have you read up much on design patterns?  [PoEAA](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/) is a good read, still very relevant..

Comment: What do you mean by required to run? Are they required to run before the object can be used for a certain thing?

Comment: Sounds like you would benefit from creating interfaces for your structure since you are pretty much forcing that these methods are implemented in the class

Comment: Those are all valid questions.  I'm generalizing, for sure!
Yes, certain Methods may become required. (and change later on)
Too many ways to describe why.  But, I only call Methods directly when I want to Customize that Method's usage.  I'm pretty sure I'm doing all I can in the __construct()

Answer (score 0):

You can basically go in several ways. there's even a pattern called [Chain of Responsability](http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-chain-of-responsibility/) just for that!

Do you need to change the methods execution on the go? you can create some scenarios for example

```
class Scenarios 
{

   public $availableScenarios = array('carPayment' => 'car payment', 
                             'carStatus' => 'car status', 
                             'carPriceCalculator' => 'calculate car price');

   public function __consctruct($myChainedExecution)
   {

       foreach ( $this->$myChainedExecution() as $executedMethod ) 
       {

         if ( in_array(!$myChainedExecution ,array_values($this->availableScenarios))) {  
             Throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Process not recognized!');
         }             

         if( !$this->$executedMethod() ) {
             Throw new \BadMethodCallException("error on $executedMethod method ");
         }

         return true;            

       }     

   }

   public function carPayment()
   {
      return  array('method1',
                    'method2',
                    'method3');
   }


  //would return true or false using attributes for internal values
  public function method1(){}
  public function method2(){}
  public function method3(){}

}
```

So when you call `$process = new Scenario('car payment');` I know that the code takes cares of that internally with a try, some execeptions you'll have everything covered